# AJAX calendar extrender control event to initiate javascript

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, vb.net, calendar

I have an AJAX calendar extender on a textbox. I am trying to bold certain dates based on an array that is sent to javascript using a script manager from VB code behind. The process is working great for the current month only.

I am updating the style to BOLD on the calendar when AJAX onClientShown event fires.

My issue is when the month is changed, it appears I need to again process my date array for the new month that the user may have advanced the calendar to.

I can not figure out how to fire the javascript function again when the AJAX calendar extender control advances months.

ASPX....

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox2_CalendarExtender" BehaviorID = "_Calendar1"
     runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox2" OnClientShown="boldCalDTS" >
```

The javascript just searches for the title tags which are the dates in the array and changes the style.

Comment: So I see what I suggested yesterday worked.

Answer (score 0):

**I have never worked with this control**

From a quick inspection of a calendar sample you could bind a delegated click handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.ajax__calendar_next .ajax__calendar_prev .ajax__calendar_month', function(){
    //code to bold the dates
});
```

This way when ever the document is clicked, if one of the elements of the calendar control that could be clicked to choose a month was clicked, the function will handle that click.